# How to force child element to have a value in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have XML (as an example) with a segment called `Type` within the segment `Order`. The segment is a one to many, so we have something like :

```
<Order>
  <Type>1</Type>
  <Type>2</Type>
  <Type>3</Type>
</Order>
```

Now the validation should be, that there always should be segment `Type` with value 1 in the segment `Order`, if not, a validation error should occur. I tried some validations, but could not get the correct result. Has someone thought on how to implement this and if this is even possible?

Answer (score 2):

### XSD 1.0

Your constraint cannot be expressed in XSD 1.0.

### XSD 1.1

Your constraint *can* be expressed in XSD 1.1 using an assertion to state that there be at least one `Type` child of `Order` that has a value of `1`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1"> 
  <xs:element name="Order">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Type" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:integer"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="Type = 1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, it helped me a lot with implementing the correct solution for this case and also know the bounderies of the XSD validation within SQL.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in **XSD 1.1**, you can use `xs:assert`element:

```
<xs:element name="Order">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string"/>

        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="count(Type[text() = '1']) > 0"/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I use the validation through SQL server which seems to only support 1.0 at this stage. Do you if this can be done from with XSD 1.0?